# Knuth's bit reversal explanation

Tags: bit-manipulation, computation-theory

I've made some progress in understanding bit reversal algorithms using non trivial (binary partition) magic constants based on D.Knuth's ideas but i fail to understand how these non continuous masks work, which seems to have bits spread around in various distances. It's always a 2-step process which swaps lsb and msb
bits, leaving the middle unchanged but it does this in multiple parts of a register at the same time. LUT, x86 **asm** based bit reversals fall under the trivial category so consider them irrelevant.

Classic Binary (Recursive) Partition Bit Reversal Algorithm 64bit (trivial)

```
x = ((x >> 1) & c1) | ( (x & c1) << 1); //0x5555555555555555ULL
x = ((x >> 2) & c2) | ( (x & c2) << 2); //0x3333333333333333ULL
x = ((x >> 4) & c3) | ( (x & c3) << 4); //0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL
x = ((x >> 8) & c4) | ( (x & c4) << 8); //0x00FF00FF00FF00FFULL
x = ((x >>16) & c5) | ( (x & c5) <<16); //0x0000FFFF0000FFFFULL
x = ((x >>32)     ) | ( (x     ) <<32); //0x00000000FFFFFFFFULL (implicit)
```

32 bit code - hackersdelight.org/revisions.pdf(2016-12-21) p.36

```
//temp
N4 t;

//17msb <- 17lsb, 15msb -> 15lsb
x = (x << 15) | (x >> 17);

//??
t = (x ^ (x >> 10)) & 0x003F801F;
x = x ^ t ^ (t << 10);

//??
t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x0E038421;
x = x ^ t ^ (t << 4);

//??
t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x22488842;
x = x ^ t ^ (t << 2);

return x;
```

64 bit code - AOCP - Vol.4 - 1A - 7.1.3 - p.13 - (70)

```
//classic adjacent bit swap
x = ((x >> 1) & c1) | ( (x & c1) << 1);

//??
t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x0300C0303030C303ULL;
x = x ^ t ^ (t << 4);

//??
t = (x ^ (x >> 8)) & 0x00C0300C03F0003FULL;
x = x ^ t ^ (t << 8);

//??
t = (x ^ (x >>20)) & 0x00000FFC00003FFFULL;
x = x ^ t ^ (t << 20);

x = (x >> 34) | (x << 30);
```

Explanation: AOCP - Vol.4 - 1A - 7.1.3 - p.13

```
    Paraphrasing Knuth: there is an operation that given a register swaps
    some msb-bits with some lsb-bits leaving some in the middle unchanged.

    Specifically we can swap bits that are k-positions apart, with k>=1
    ie. bits are not overlapping. Operation is given below.

    Let 64bit register (x). We want to swap 25-msb and 25-lsb of x, with 14bits  (25 + 14 + 25): 64
    in the middle left as is. We set k = 64-25 = 39, m = (pow(2,25)-1) = 0x1FFFFFF 

    (t:temp)(x:input)(m:mask)
    t = (x ^ (x >> k)) & m;     // ((x-25-msb) xor (x-25-lsb)) -> t-25-lsb
    t = t ^ (t << k);           // t-25-lsb -> get copied to -> t-25-msb, so t-25-msb/lsb holds: x-msb-25 ^ x-lsb-25
    x = x ^ t;                  // on x-25-msb, msb gets calceled out, so x-25-msb <- x-25-lsb, t-14-middle is zero
                                // so x-14-midddle xor 0x0 remains as is, x-25-lsb <- x-25-msb because it cancels out with xor op.

    //above 3line operation in 2 lines
    t = (x ^ (x >> k)) & m;     
    x = (t ^ (t << k)) ^ x;     //line 2

    //common ways line 2 is displayed
    x = (t + (t << k)) ^ x;     //equiv. line 2
    x = (t | (t << k)) ^ x;     //equiv. line 2
    x = (t ^ (t << k)) ^ x;     //equiv. line 2
    x = x ^ t ^ (t << k)  ;     //equiv. line 2

    operation with letters:
    [a,b,c] -> [ 0,0,a] ^ [a,b,c] -> [a,b,c^a] & mask -> [0,0,c^a] -> [0,0,c^a] ^ [c^a,0,0] -> [c^a,0,c^a] ->
     -> [a,b,c] ^ [c^a,0,c^a] -> [c,b,a]
```

Another 64bit reverse (Hacker's Delight)

```
//swap halves
x = (x << 32) | (x >> 32);

//its the 32bit knuth bit reverse: [17bit m<-l],[15bit m->l] step: applied on both 32bit up/down half of 64bit register.
x = (x & 0x0001FFFF0001FFFFLL) << 15 |  (x & 0xFFFE0000FFFE0000LL) >> 17;

t = (x ^ (x >> 10)) & 0x003F801F003F801FULL;
x = (t | (t << 10)) ^ x;

t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x0E0384210E038421ULL;
x = (t | (t << 4)) ^ x;

t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x2248884222488842ULL;
x = (t | (t << 2)) ^ x;
```

Hacker's Delight - Figure 7-4 - p.37

```
x = (x << 31) | (x >> 33);

t = (x ^ (x >> 20)) & 0x00000FFF800007FFULL;
x = (t |(t << 20)) ^ x;

t = (x ^ (x >> 8)) & 0x00F8000F80700807ULL;
x = (t |(t << 8)) ^ x;

t = (x ^ (x >> 4)) & 0x0808708080807008ULL;
x = (t |(t << 4)) ^ x;

t = (x ^ (x >> 2)) & 0x1111111111111111ULL;
x = (t |(t << 2)) ^ x;
```

Comment: Looks like it's an application of the classic [XOR-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) idea, just with swapping bits in a register instead of swapping variables.

Comment: Love the fact that ARM has this built into its insrtuctions as a 1 cycle op.  Really useful when doing AES Encryption type operations.  Random thought, but wanted to show that this has real world use.

Comment: I always thought bit_reverse would make a nice PRNG step, albeit slow and rev((rev(x)) = x, if applied twice. Ciphers,Hash functions, ECC, and PRNG are all related ie. 'chaotic mappings'. Also the reason i bother with portable - C like algorithms is because there is a niche: Microcontrollers.

Comment: Bit reversal comes up a number of other places, such as generalized CRC calculation.  I also used it to great effect in some DSP algorithms.

Comment: Also, I ran a test on my Phenom-II X4 Linux box.  (Yes, this box is getting old.)  It appears that a bog-standard binary-recursive algorithm working from MSB to LSB works best with GCC 7.1 back to GCC 4.6.

The fancier algorithms from TAOCP and Hacker's Delight don't actually perform as well, for whatever reason, and the binary-recursive approaches perform slightly differently across different GCC versions.

I've put my code here: http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/dl/bitrev.cc

log2_msb_b is the most consistent performer across multiple GCC versions.

Comment: Keep coming back to a problem with a clean/refreshed mindset will get the problem solved. Lets focus in these 2 lines: